# Jquery select only from modal page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage that opens a modal form. I validate the modal form using a JQuery function. The problem is that my function is checking all fields in both the modal AND the page behind it.

```
//validate function 
function validateFields() {
    var valid = true;
    $('.required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            addError(this, 'required');
            valid = false;
        }
    });
}

//in my save function
function saveLead(){
    if (validateFields()) {
         //save
    }
}
```

My validate function is checking all fields with the `required` class on both my page and modal. How can I get it to just use my page?

UPDATE: 
this has complications because my validation function is reused on many pages and is not set up to accept a specific form to check
Is such a thing possible or do I have to do major revisions to the validation or modal in order for this to work?

Comment: Don't you have an id or a class on your modal so you can precise the selector ? Like $('.modal_class .required') or $('#modal_id .required')...

Comment: _$('**formUniqueSelector** .required')_

Comment: Why not just use `required` attribute.

Comment: can you post the html for the modal? @MateoBarahona's solution is the correct answer, we just need to know what the id/class of the modal or form is

Comment: I can't specify the id because the validation is reused all over and does not take in an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could detect the form from which the submit button is clicked. Something like the below should work.

```
//validate function 
function validateFields($submittedForm) {
    var valid = true;
    $('$submittedForm .required').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            addError(this, 'required');
            valid = false;
        }
    });
}

//in my save function

// Find the form there 'this' is the submit button
var $submittedForm = $(this).closest('form');

function saveLead($submittedForm){
    if (validateFields($submittedForm)) {
         //save
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good idea but I don't have a way to pass the form to my validation function. see edit

Comment: This should be possible, how are you detecting the form submit?

Comment: its an angular app and I call the validateForm function from the save function

Comment: I'm not that familiar with angular, but if you can detect the submit element then you should be able to adapt my example. Try debugging with the following code at the start of your save function to see if $(this) is an element that is being passed to your function.

    console.log($(this).html);

Comment: what I did was: in the validate function I set `$submittedFrom = $submittedFrom || ''` so that i don;t ;have to pass in a form from everywhere I call it